# iOS, chart that loads in tableView cell somehow also loads in another cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subview

So I have a tableView with a set of buttons in each cell. These are the options for a user to vote from.

[image: TableView with options]

When a user presses an option, a chart loads that shows the poll results.

[image: Poll results after button pressed]

However, when I scroll down, the chart appears inexplicably on another tableView cell. None of the buttons in that cell were ever pressed. Additionally, the chart loads in the second cell with the data of the first. I have been stuck on this for hours and have no idea why that is.

[image]

**EDIT**: Here is the code for the tableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pollCell") as! PollCell

let titled = titles[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(polltitled: titled, num: indexPath.row)

return cell
}
```

And here are the methods for the Poll Cell:

```
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

var options = [String]()
var counts = [Int]()

self.loadedChart = false

@IBOutlet weak var chart: HorizontalBarChartView!

func configure(polltitled: String, num: Int) {

    self.pollTitle.text = polltitled
    self.row = num
    self.runRemove() { (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            if (loadedChart == false) {
                self.loadChart()
            }
        }
        else {

        }
        }
}

func runRemove(completion:(_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        self.pollTitle.tag = 999
        self.chart.tag = 998

        for object in self.contentView.subviews {
            if ((object.tag != 999)  && (object.tag != 998)) {
                object.removeFromSuperview()

                }

    }

        completion(true)
}

func loadChart(){
    ref.child("poll").child(StaticVariables.currentEventQR).child(self.pollTitle.text!).observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in


        self.counts.removeAll()
        self.options.removeAll()
        for item in snapshot.children {

            let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: (item as AnyObject).key)

            let option = childSnapshot.key

            self.options.append(option)

        }
        self.loadCounts()
        self.createButtons()
    }

}

func loadCounts() {

    for i in self.options {
        self.ref.child("poll").child(StaticVariables.currentEventQR).child(self.pollTitle.text!).child(i).observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in

            for item in snapshot.children {

                    let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: (item as AnyObject).key)

                    let countsValue = childSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let count = countsValue?["Counter"] as! Int
                    self.counts.append(count)


            }

        }


    }




}

func createButtons() {
    var i = 1
    var height = 0
    if ((self.pollTitle.text?.characters.count)! > 37){
        height = 22
    }
    for option in self.options{
        let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: Int(self.contentView.frame.size.width - 320)/2, y: 59+60*(i-1)+height, width: 320, height: 33))
        if ((i)%2 == 1){
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 253/255, green: 185/255, blue: 39/255, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 107/255, blue: 182/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PollCell.optionOne(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = i
        self.contentView.addSubview(btn)
        btn.setTitle(option, for: .normal)
        i += 1

    }
}

@IBAction func optionOne(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.loadedChart = true
    delegate.refresh(self.row)
    self.options.reverse()
    self.counts.reverse()
    self.setChart(dataPoints: self.options, values: self.counts)
    ref.child("poll").child(StaticVariables.currentEventQR).child(pollTitle.text!).child((sender.titleLabel?.text!)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


        let item = snapshot.children.allObjects[0]
        let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: (item as AnyObject).key)

        let responseID = childSnapshot.key
        let reponseValue = childSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        var response = reponseValue?["Counter"] as! Int
        response += 1
        self.ref.child("poll").child(StaticVariables.currentEventQR).child(self.pollTitle.text!).child((sender.titleLabel?.text!)!).child("count").setValue(["Counter": response])

    })
    self.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: self.chart)

}


func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Int]) {

    self.chartHeight.constant = CGFloat((RowHeightCounter.sharedInstance.counters[row])*62+39)

    chart.chartDescription?.text = ""
    chart.noDataText = ""
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(counts[i]))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Votes")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chart.data = chartData
    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: options)

    chart.xAxis.granularity = 1
    self.chart.alpha = 1.0
    chart.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)

}
```

Comment: Seems you have a bug. Good luck

Comment: Do you load the charts asynchronously? And can you show us the cell code please, I have an idea what your problem is but would like to confirm it first.

Comment: Just edited and added the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `UITableView` reuses cells rather than creating new ones all the time. If the table had enough rows in it you would see that chart appear numerous times as you scrolled.

Once you add a chart to a cell it is there until removed so every time that cell gets used again the chart will be there.

`UITableViewCell` has a convient method that gets celled when it is about to be reused, `prepareForReuse()`. Implement this method and reset anything in the cell that needs to be reset before it appears again.

This does mean that you might need to rethink the interface between the cell and the data source. Maybe create a model object that holds the questions and result data along with wether the user has answered it or not. The data source could then hold an array of questions and pass the correct question to each cell. The cell could then configure itself based on the question

On a side note, I wouldn't remove the various views when changing from the question to the results. I would contain all the question stuff in one container view and all the chart stuff in another. Then I would set `isHidden` on the two containers as needed. This will keep your scrolling frame rate higher.